# Change multiple background-images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, hover

In my css page, i have this as code:

```
header {
    background:url('afbeeldingen/r.png'),url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 33%, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size:26%,960px 130px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Now in my html page, I want to use JQuery to change the first image when I hover my navigation bar.
Can you please help me?

Comment: You don't need to use js/jquery for that, css pseudo class :hover should be a better choice, see Manish Jangir's answer

Answer (score 3):

Use class header to your navigation button wherever you want to do this work

```
.header {
    background:url('afbeeldingen/r.png'),url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 33%, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size:26%,960px 130px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


<script>
$(".header").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg'),url('Afbeeldingen/anotherhoverimage.jpg')"); 
});

$(".header").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).css("background","url('afbeeldingen/r.png'),url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg')"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstanded it. The black.jpg must remain. When i hover my navigation menu I wrote in my html page, the r.png image should change to another image

Comment: It'll change the whole 2 images, isn't it? I think it must be like this: `background:url('ANOTHERIMAGE'),url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg');`

Comment: We must do it with JQuery, it's a school assignment

Comment: When I use this code, my total background changes to black.jpg and r.png combined. I only want the r.png image to be changed;

Comment: ok than remove url('Afbeeldingen/black.jpg'), from your .hover function

Comment: Then it still uses my new image as a total background, while it should only replace the other image I've used

Answer (score 3):

There is no current native method in jQuery to switch out the order of the background images (and hence the one that is displayed). Here's the code to swap the background image order for an element with two background images by parsing the links and swapping them:

```
var bg=$(this).css('background-image').split('),url(');
if(bg.length==2) $(this).css('background-image','url('+bg[1]+','+bg[0]+')');
```