# Change SPECIFIC background image in div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has more than one image set as a background.

```
background-image: 
       url(/Content/frontend/images/left.png), 
       url(/Content/frontend/images/right.png), 
       url(http://IMAGE_I_WANT_TO_TARGET),
       linear-gradient($dark 0%, $light 100%);
```

If i target my div and change the background image, it overwrites all other images:

```
$(".div").css("background-image", "url(http://placehold.it/300?text=asdasd)");
```

Is it possible to target just the 3rd image and change it?

Comment: No - you would need to provide the entire property again with the updated value.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624199/change-multiple-background-images-with-jquery

Comment: Your style is come from a .css file or from inline styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Suppose you have 3 background images in your div.

```
var images = $('.div').css('background-image'); // get all background images
var i = images.split(',');
var imageArray = [];
imageArray = imageArray.concat(i);
imageArray[2] = 'url(4th-image.jpg)'; // set your new image
$('.div').css('background-image',imageArray);
```

Comment: I have manually hard coded it. I don't see any problem with your code so I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you for your time. :)